# SP2010 to SP2013 UI upgrade using powershell?

Tags: powershell, upgrade

I upgraded an SP2010 Content Database with a single site collection to SP2013 using the database attach method.
I will eventually be upgrading it to SP2016.
The upgrade went fine apart from a few non-fatal errors related to few missing features.
Since an intermediate UI upgrade step is necessary to proceed with the upgrade to SP2016.
The Site collection needs administrators to be changed(it's from a different domain) and I don't want to add members to it to just perform the UI upgrade.

Is it possible to perform the UI upgrade using a PowerShell script so that I can automate the upgrade sequence 2010 through 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the Upgrade-SPSite cmdlet.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://<site url>"
Upgrade-SPSite -Identity $site -VersionUpgrade
```

Hope this helps!

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161257.aspx